# Error integrating Google Analytics in PyroCMS

Tags: php, google-analytics, pyrocms

There was no error before i filled up the *Google Analytics Setting* in the **Integration** option of **Setting** menu in *Admin Panel*.
When I submitted the form after filling up the *Google Analytics Setting* and went to **Dashboard**, the following error occurred and the *graph* is not displaying in the **Dashboard**.

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message:  Undefined variable: http_response_header
Filename: libraries/Analytics.php
Line Number: 424

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message:  Undefined variable: http_response_header
Filename: libraries/Analytics.php
Line Number: 427
```

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google analytics uses CURL. In a shared hosting CURL might be disabled, So such problems are likely to occur.